SwiftData One-To-Many Relation not Reflecting
I have two models in SwiftData Folders and Projects.

@Model
final class Project {
    var projectTitle: String
    var folder: Folder?
    init(
        projectTitle: String,
        folder: Folder,
  
    ) {
        self.projectTitle = projectTitle
        self.folder = folder

    }}

@Model
final class Folder {
    @Attribute(.unique) var folderName: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Project.folder) var projects: [Project] = []
    
    init(
        folderName: String,
        projects: [Project] = []
    )
    {
        self.folderName = folderName
    }
}


The issue that I am currently facing is that when I create a new Project assigned to a specific folder, this update is not reflected in my code to retrieve the folders and refresh the folders array that I use in the view. The change is not reflected except when I rerun the App from Xcode. Note that when I fetch the projects on their own I can see the newly created project without an issue and the folder is assigned correctly as well.
    func getAllFolders(modelContext: ModelContext) -> [Folder] {
        do {
            return try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Folder>())
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


Any help is greatly appreaciated

Please include a reproducible example
